# Why is it clear that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\sigma (X_{1},...,X_{n})$ for IID random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, random-variables, martingales

Why is it clear that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\sigma (X_{1},...,X_{n})$

Example:

Let $(X_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence of IID RV's where $E[X_{1}]=0$, now define $S_{n}:=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$

Let $\mathcal{F}_{n}:=\sigma (X_{1},...,X_{n})$ and show $E[S_{n+1}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]=S_{n}$

I agree with the solution up to a point:

$E[S_{n+1}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}E[X_{i}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]=E[X_{n+1}\vert \mathcal{F}_{n}]+\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}X_{i}$

and then it is said that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}_{n}$, and I do not agree with that unless I do not understand IID correctly. To my understanding, IID in this case would mean:

$X_{n+1}$ is independent from $\sigma (X_{i})$ where $1\leq i\leq n$. The definition does not say that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\sigma (X_{1},...,X_{n})$. Or is that in actual fact the definition of IID?

Comment: $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ is shorthand for $$\sigma\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n \sigma(X_i) \right). $$ Since $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\sigma(X_i)$ for $1\leqslant i\leqslant n$, the claim in question follows.

Comment: @Math1000 I know what $\sigma (X_{1},...,X_{n})$ stands for, but the fact is that $\sigma (X_{1},...,X_{n})$ is "larger" than $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sigma (X_{i})$ and hence there may be some $A \in \sigma (X_{1},...,X_{n})$ and $\notin \bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}\sigma (X_{i})$ so that independence does necessarily follow

Comment: How have you defined IID? I think that it's definition usually includes the property you're asking about - I mean, the idea is that you run a bunch of trials, without any influence on each other - and pairwise independence is not strong enough to model that.

Comment: you seem confused between mutual independence and pairwise independence.  the former is much stronger and is usually (always?) what "IID" means.

Answer (score 2):

The first "i" in "iid" means that the family of random variables $(X_i)_{i\in\mathbb N}$ is mutually independent. By definition, this means that for every pair of disjoint sets $A,B\subseteq \mathbb N$ the $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(X_i\colon i\in A)$ and $\sigma(X_j\colon j\in B)$ are independent. In particular, taking $A=\{n+1\}$ and $B=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ answers your question.